# Morphism between Multiplicative groups mod $p^{n}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and for $n\geq 1$ let $G_n = \left({\mathbb{Z}}/{{p^{n+1}}\mathbb{Z}}\right)^{*}$.

Let's Define morphisms
$$\pi_n : G_{n+1} \rightarrow G_{n}$$
de projection $x \bmod p^{n+1} \mapsto x \bmod p^n$.

The projection induces a long exact sequence

$$0 \longrightarrow \ker(\pi_{n}) \longrightarrow G_{n+1} \overset{\pi_n}\longrightarrow G_n \longrightarrow 0.$$

Does this sequence Split? I found a morphism

\begin{align}
f_n:  G_n &\longrightarrow G_{n+1}\\
\end{align}

defined by $x \pmod{p^n}\mapsto x^{p} \pmod{p^{n+1}}$, I know each $f_n$ is a morphism, but I have no idea if $f_n$ is a section of $\pi_n$.

Comment: You should use $1$s in your sequence, because your groups are multiplicative, not additive...

Answer (score 1):

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order $(p-1)p^{n-1}$.

If *any* surjection $(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+2}\mathbb{Z})^*\to(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^*$ splits, then you necessarily have that
$$C_{(p-1)p^{n+1}}\cong C_{(p-1)p^{n}}\oplus C_p,$$
where $C_m$ denotes the cyclic group of order $m$.
Clearly, this is impossible if $n\geq 1$. In particular, your map cannot split for $n\geq 1$.

On the other hand, for $n=0$, you have $x\bmod p$ and you map it to $x^p\bmod p^2$ via $f_0$, and then to $x^p\bmod p$ via $\pi_0$. But by Fermat’s Little Theorem, $x\equiv x^p\pmod{p}$, so you end up back where you started, so $f_0$ does split $\pi_0$, which is the case you did not ask about.